# Tracking ref changes in React

Tags: reactjs

Due to some complications using 3rd party frameworks, I'm having to grab the refs from the components and save it to an array of refs

```
const refs = useRef([]);

return (<>{someProp.map((p, i) => (<3rdParty prop={p} ref={(ref) => {refs.current[i] = ref}}></3rdParty>)}</>)
```

However, because these are refs, I have no way of tracking their changes. What I would really like to use are states, but they aren't really to be used inside a render function.

I've tried using callback refs, but it didn't seem like it'd work in this case since I'm mapping through an array, and whenever I call setState inside the callback one after another, the state has not been updated, which leads to an infinite loop.

Is there a better way of grabbing these refs while keeping track of what's being added / removed?

Comment: When you say *tracking their changes* what exactly do you mean? A ref gives you access to the dom element, anything else should be exposed as a prop of the 3rd party component. For example a `button` has an `onClick` prop that takes a callback

Comment: @Bugbeeb So the 3rd party component I'm using exposes one of its objects via ref. So when I set the ref, instead of getting the DOM element, I get an object that contains the stuff that the component has. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to somehow accurately track the changes, so that whenever the prop that's being used to map changes, I can call an useEffect or so accordingly